# Restoing nuget using nuget.exe in jenkins pipeline giving some incorrect error log

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-cli, nuget-restore

Before Update to .net6 -
I have projects in my solution which consist of .netstandard2.1, .netframeword4.8 and .netcore3.1 projects. I this case I dont have any problems. I have a script to restore nugets in build server which uses nuget.exe and its works fine.

After Update to .net6
I have updated all my .netcore3.1 projects to .net6 (since .netcore3.1 is out of support).
In development I am not facing any issue. Everything is working just fine. But when I am running the same script to restore nugets its giving some strange errors. I have updated the nuget.exe to v6.5

Lets say I have a project named Proj1 which targets .netframework 4.8 and other project named Proj2 target .net6.
Now when the script runs to restore nuget, It shows this error:

NU1201: Project Proj1 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Project Proj1 supports: net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8).

My Proj1 is already targeting .net4.8

I tried updation nuget.exe multiple times with different version, still not working